# child value is returning undefined

Tags: jquery

Take a look at my function:

```
$(".select-default").on("click", function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").on("click", function() {
      var x = $(".select-default label").children()[0];
      $(".select-default label").text($(this).text()+x);
    });
  $(this).off("click");
 });
```

I'm trying to figure out why x prints undefined, where I expect it to print 
the actual child node:

```
<span class="caret"></span>
```

Edit. Here is the markup:

```
<ul class="select-default select-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
<label for="select" id="select_value">Select Action <span class="caret"></span></label>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
<li><a href="#">Value 0</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Value 1s</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Value 2</a></li>            
<li><a href="#">Value 3</a></li>
```

I'm trying to get the entire span node nested inside label, and join it 
with the value of the clicked a tag. x should be printing:

```
<span class="caret"></span>
```

Comment: please share the related markup

Comment: What is this `$(this).text()+x` ? string+object ?

Comment: What is the result of `alert($(".select-default label").children().size())` ?

Comment: Added markup, and elaborated a bit more.

Answer (score 1):

`$(".select-default label").children()[0]` will be returning `undefined` because, from the looks of it the `label` has text node as the child. text nodes of a element will not get selected by `.children()`, instead you can use `$(".select-default label").text()` to get the text of the `label` element

```
$(".select-default").on("click", function() {
    $(".dropdown-menu li a").on("click", function() {
        var a = $($(".select-default label").contents().get(0));
        a.replaceWith($(this).text())
    });
    $(this).off("click");
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/uaqHg/)

Answer (score 0):

The Answer was simple.

Use append(x). Replace:

```
$(".select-default label").text($(this).text()+x);
```

With:

```
$(".select-default label").text($(this).text()).append(x);
```

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

this could work:

```
  $(".dropdown-menu li a").on("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $label = $(".select-default").children("label");
      $label.text($(this).text());          
  });
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/uaqHg/2/